# bash does not find HTK commands

Tags: linux, bash, htk

I am using HTK for quite some time now and it used to work flawlessly. Off late (might have changed some environmental variables in the meantime, cant remember which ones though!), all the HTK commands are "not to be found". Executing HCompV for example gave a

> bash: /usr/local/bin/HCompV: No such file or directory

even though HCompV is visible in  /usr/local/bin.
Recompiling and installing HTK was futile. 
Running HCompV (or any other HTK commands) from the bin folder of the compiled HTK also gave the same error. Any ideas why?

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/bin/HCompV` output?

Comment: This is what it says  >/usr/local/bin/HCompV: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!
I had to reinstall the 32 bit libs on my 64 bit ubuntu though I had it installed previously. Any ideas why this helped?

These is what I did:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ia32-libs
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386

This [page](https://superuser.com/questions/344533/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-bash-but-the-file-exists) has more details.

Thank you guys for your reply. You guys rock.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
hash -d HCompV
```

or

```
hash -r
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

what were the commands to recompile?

```
make clean
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Clearing the bash cache followed by reinstall did not help. Post reinstallation 'type HCompV' gave 'HCompV is hashed (/usr/local/bin/HCompV)'

Comment: It seems weird that the code execution from the compiled HTK directory also gave an error, namely,`$HTKRoot/bin.linux/> ./HCompV` gave `bash: ./HCompV: No such file or directory`